# Open Dialog from Notification

Tags: android, dialog, notifications

I have a notification displayed. Now I want this to happen:

When I click on the notification, I would like to open a Dialog, where I print only 1 string.

Now, I can't work it out, what to do here, when I create notification:

```
...
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, {how to open dialog}); 
...
```

Then 1 button, for example "OK", which will close the dialog.

Please, help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do exactly this in one of my apps. In the notification you need to do something like this:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent("com.yourcompany.yourapp.MAINACTIVITY").putExtra("fromnotification", true);
```

Inside your main activity use the onResume() method to check for this extra:

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
            super.onResume();

            if (getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fromnotification", false) == true)
            {
                    getActivity().getIntent().removeExtra("fromnotification");
                    startActivityForResult(
                                    new Intent("com.yourcompany.yourapp.DIALOGACTIVITY"), 123);
            }

    }
```

This code displays an activity with a dialog style, but there is no reason why it can't create a dialog inside the if statement though.